# Match results in multiple tables MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

Hi I have a query that is giving me a few problems and it was suggested I ask a separate question about the end result rather than the problem.

So I have three tables and some user input.

the tables are:

- users,
- usersLanguages and
- usersSkills

each table has a related ID the users table has ID and on the other two they have userID to match skills and languages to users

the user input is dynamic but for example it can be 1 for usersLanguages and 2 for usersSkills

The user input is taken from a form and what i need to do is match get the results of users 
depending on the language IDs or skill ids passed through. for example i can pass two user ids and three language ID's.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.ID, users.name
FROM users 
INNER JOIN usersSkills 
ON users.ID = usersSkills.userID 
INNER JOIN usersLanguages ON users.ID = usersLanguages.userID 
WHERE activated = "1" 
      AND type = "GRADUATE" AND usersSkills.skillID IN(2) 
      AND usersLanguages.languageID IN(2)
GROUP BY usersSkills.userID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1,
         usersLanguages.userID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: what about to show that query?

Comment: @genesisφ that's what i got so far thanks to some help but it doesn't work because of HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mix `group by` and `having` clauses.
having is not a part of group by, in fact you can have `having` without a group by, in which case it will work as a more capable *(and slower)* `where` clause.

```
SELECT u.ID, u.name
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN usersSkills us ON u.ID = us.userID 
INNER JOIN al ON u.ID = ul.userID 
WHERE u.activated = '1' 
      AND u.type LIKE 'GRADUATE' AND us.skillID IN('2') 
      AND ul.languageID IN('2')
GROUP BY u.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

- because of the join criteria, `ul.userID = us.userID = u.ID` so it makes no sense to group by both. Just group by `u.id`, because that's the ID you select after all.
- `u.name` is functionally dependent on ID, so that does not need to be listed <sup>(*)</sup>.
- When doing a test like `u.type = 'GRADUATE'`, I prefer to do `u.type LIKE 'GRADUATE'`  because `LIKE` is case insensitive and `=` may not be depending on the collation, but that's just me.
- `Distinct` is not needed; `group by` already makes the results distinct.

`Having` works on the resultset up to and including `group by`, so in this case you need only one having clause. If you want to have more, you need to treat them the same as a `where` clause:

```
having count(*) = 1 AND SUM(money) > 10000
```

<sup>(*)</sup> *this is only true in MySQL, in other SQL's you need to list all non-aggregated selected columns in your group by clause. Whether they are functionally dependent on the group by column or not. This slows things down and makes for very long query-syntax, but it does prevent a few beginners errors.

Personally I like the MySQL way of doing things.*

Comment: Thanks but I tried that problem with that is that it will match a user if is is any one of those IDs i need to to match all of them that's why i had the having count there

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
SELECT * from users left join usersLanguage on users.id=usersLanguage.userID 
left join usersSkills on usersSkills.userID=users.id 
where usersLanguage.id in (1, 2, 3) and usersSkills.id in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY users.id
```

will probably work

Comment: like i mentioned above I need it to match each ID in the IN() that's why I have the having COUNT(*) results to match

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT users.ID,user.name
FROM users 
INNER JOIN usersSkills ON users.ID = usersSkills.userId
INNER JOIN AND usersLanguages ON users.ID = usersLanguages.userID
WHERE activate = '1'
AND type = 'GRADUATE'
AND usersSkill.skillID IN (2)
AND usersLanguages.languageID IN (2)
GROUP BY users.ID
```